# 'System.IO.Directory' does not contain a definition for 'EnumerateDirectories'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have this code for looping through folders in a location, but I am getting some error I can't understand, here's the code

```
var directoryNames = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(filePath).Where(dir => dir.EndsWith(".user"));

foreach (var directoryName in directoryNames)
{
    // some stuff
}
```

I get this error

> 'System.IO.Directory' does not contain a definition for 'EnumerateDirectories'

If this is something to do with the Framework version (my project has Framework 2.0, lowest possible so it can install easier on all machines), can you please:

- Tell me an alternative code that would work like this, and will work on Framework 2.0

or

- Tell me if I can use higher version of Framework, and guarantee that it will be supported on most machines (meaning the user will not be required to download Framework)

Comment: `EnumerateDirectories` is available in .NET 4 and greater. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Sajeetharan I need a folder, not a file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EnumerateDirectories` was introduced in .NET 4.0. For .NET 2.0, you could use [`GetDirectories`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. You can specify your filter as a search pattern; this would cause the filtering to be performed by the filesystem itself.

```
var directoryNames = Directory.GetDirectories(filePath, "*.user");
foreach (var directoryName in directoryNames)
{
    // ...
}
```